# Normalising pandas data frame using StandardScaler() excluding a particular column

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, normalization

So I have a data frame which I formed by merging training (labeled) and test (unlabelled) data frames. And to un-append the test data frame I have kept a column which has a identifier if the row belonged to training or test.
Now I have to normalize all the values in all the columns except for this one column "Sl No." but I am not finding any way to pass this one column.
Here's what I was doing

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data_norm = data_x_filled.copy() #Has training + test data frames combined to form single data frame
normalizer = StandardScaler()
data_array = normalizer.fit_transform(data_norm)
data_norm = pd.DataFrame(data_array,columns = data_norm.columns).set_index(data_norm.index)
```

I just want to exclude the column "Sl No." for normalization but want to retain it after normalization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this it may work use `numpy` as `np`:

```
data_norm = data_x_filled.copy() #Has training + test data frames combined to form single data frame
normalizer = StandardScaler()
data_array = normalizer.fit_transform(data_norm.ix[:,data_norm.columns!='SI No'])
data_norm = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((data_norm['SI No'].values,data_array)),columns = data_norm.columns).set_index(data_norm.index)
```

Comment: This worked :).
I replaced my solution with yours since I was essentially dropping the column and after all the processing was adding it back. 
This is shorter and more elegant.

Comment: @Shivendra Glad could help you :).